# How can I refresh the adjustment tax after changing the line-item price?

Tags: commerce

I create orders programmatically, and I have a tax problem: the order, after changing the line item price, always has the tax cost with the old product price.
How can I refresh the adjustment tax after changing the line-item price?

```
foreach ($entity_ids as $entity_id) {
    $abo = Node::load($entity_id);

    //utilisateur
    $user = $abo->get('field_utilisateur')->getValue()[0]['target_id'];
    $utilisateur = \Drupal\user\Entity\User::load($user);

    //profile
    $entity_manager = \Drupal::entityTypeManager();
    $profile = $entity_manager->getStorage('profile')->load($user);

    //abonnement
    $nid= $abo->id();

    //livraison
    $date_livraison = new DateTime();
    $date_livraison->modify('next friday');

    //ligne de commande
    $line_items = array();
    $abo_array= $abo->get('field_abo_produits')->getValue();

    foreach ($abo_array as $abo_item) {
        $ligne = $abo_item['target_id'];        
        //load produit abonnement      
        $item = \Drupal\commerce_order\Entity\OrderItem::load($ligne);
        $quantite = $item->getQuantity();
        $produit = $item->getPurchasedEntity();

        $order_item = \Drupal\commerce_order\Entity\OrderItem::create([
            'type' => 'default',
            'purchased_entity' => $produit,
            'quantity' => $quantite,
            //'unit_price' => $role_price,
        ]);

        $order_item->save();        
        array_push($line_items,$order_item);        
    }

    //creation de la commande
    $order = \Drupal\commerce_order\Entity\Order::create([
        'type' => 'default',
        'store_id' => 1,
        'checkout_flow' => 'boulangerie',      
        'uid' => $user,
        'billing_profile' =>$profile,
        'field_abonnement' => $nid,
        'placed' => time(),
        'field_date_livraison' =>$date_livraison->format('Y-m-d'),
        'order_items' =>$line_items          
    ]);    

    $order->save(); 
    $order->set('order_number', $order->id());        
    $order->save();
    $order->set('state', 'complete');
    $order->save();       

    //prix custo
    foreach ($order->getItems() as $ligne_de_commande) {

        $produit = $ligne_de_commande->getPurchasedEntity();
        //prix
        if ($utilisateur->hasRole('biocoop')) {
            $role_price = $produit->get('field_prix_biocoop');
            $role = 'biocoop';
        }

        if ($utilisateur->hasRole('montagne')) {
            $role_price = $produit->get('field_prix_montagne');
            $role = 'montagne';          
        }

        if ($utilisateur->hasRole('vente_directe')) {
            $role_price = $produit->get('field_prix_vd');
            $role = 'vente_directe';
        }

        $unit_price = new  \Drupal\commerce_price\Price($role_price->number, 'EUR');

        $ligne_de_commande->setUnitPrice($unit_price);
        $ligne_de_commande->save();

    }

    $order->save();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by @d70rr3s, the OrderRefresh service is used. You can can inject the service interface into your own service or controller or use it directly in procedural code.

The service itself is `commerce_order.order_refresh`.

See:

- Drupal\commerce_order\OrderRefreshInterface
- Drupal\commerce_order\OrderRefresh

Example:

```
$orderRefresh = \Drupal::service('commerce_order.order_refresh');
$orderRefresh->refresh($order);
```

Answer (score 0):

Order refresh is done via a service, this service is called every time an order is saved. Check the module [documentation](https://docs.drupalcommerce.org/commerce2/developer-guide/orders/order-refresh-and-process).